# Qt4 QString causes error

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have no errors during compilation, But when I run program it shows error. Pleas help me out in this.

Cmake version: 3.7.2

GCC version: 6.3.0

`/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Project.dir/main.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN7QString4freeEPNS_4DataE'`
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

**My code is:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

QApplication app(argc, argv);

QDialog *d = new QDialog;
d->setMinimumSize(400, 400);

QTextEdit *l = new QTextEdit(d);

const char* str = "Hello world";
QString qstr = QString::fromAscii(str);
b->setText(qstr);
d->show();

return app.exec();
}
```

CmakeFile:
https://pastebin.com/01Qm7c4p

Comment: show your CMakeLists.txt

Comment: It means the dynamic Qt library is not found at runtime. Read about Qt deployment, and consider using LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: I added CmakeFile in pastebin.